# What is the difference between 0 << 16 and 0 << 20?

Tags: objective-c, c

What is the difference between 0 << 16 and 0 << 20? I found it in UIViewAnimationOptions.

Comment: The difference is `0`.

Comment: Just to confirm @Charles Bailey: http://codepad.org/QVAmI0Gx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoreing the *UIViewAnimationOptions* part ...

- If your `int`s are 16 bits or less, both expressions invoke UB (can't speak of differences in this case)
- if they are between 17 and 20 bits long, `0 << 16` is 0; `0 << 20` is UB
- if they are 21 bits or longer, there is no difference

*UB means [Undefined Behaviour](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior).*

Answer (score 6):

There isn't. They are both 0

```
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   = 5 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     = 6 << 20,
   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  = 7 << 20,
```

The UIViewAnimationOptionTransition settings are all concerned with setting the bits 20-23. UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone is zero, however, it is defined in the same manner as the other UIViewAnimationTransitions for consistency.

Both of the given values are zero which indicates they are both the default settings, if you don't pass transition flag you'll get no transition by default. But you can also specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

`0 << 16` is shifting left 16 bits, `0 << 20` shifting 20 bits. Both end up being 0.

I'm guessing it's being done for clarity, just like sizeof(char) is sometimes used in malloc.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the architecture: except for undefined behaviour in corner cases, shifting left (or right) is explicitly defined as being the same as multiplying by 2 the correct number of times.

Comment: @pmg Makes sense. I'll remove that part.

Answer (score 3):

The fact there are 2 of them indicates that by setting either you don't actually do anything.  However you help to self document your code which makes it far easier for others to understand that what you are doing is actually what you meant to do.

Answer (score 2):

They're bitwise left shift operators. The general gist is that by using such a syntax in the enum definition, you can combine multiple animations using the bitwise OR operator. For example, when passing in animation options you could write

```
(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |  UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp)
```

It would perform a curl up with an ease-in-out curve, and repeat when done. This is accomplished by looking at the individual bits in the final result.

BTW `0 << 16` is  `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` and `0 << 20` is `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone`